# Fortran's "Read" and "Print" don't work in a terminal

Tags: fortran

I am new in Linux environment and now I am starting to use Mac OS X's Terminal. Long time ago, I always coded Fortran in Plato editor. Now I want to run this simple code:

```
program sum
real :: answer,x,y
print *, 'Enter two numbers' read *, x
read *, y
answer=x+y
print *, 'The total is ', answer 
end program sum
```

In Plato, running this code will trigger the console to ask the user to input values owing to the `read` statement in the code above. But when I run it through Bash Terminal using

```
$ gfortran -llapack sum.f95
```

It shows the following messages

```
sum.f95:4:28:

print *, 'Enter two numbers' read *, x
                        1
Error: Syntax error in PRINT statement at (1)
sum.f95:7:33:

print *, 'The total is ', answer end program sum
                             1
Error: Syntax error in PRINT statement at (1)
f951: Error: Unexpected end of file in ‘sum.f95’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not syntactically correct. ayou put two statements on one line

```
 print *, 'Enter two numbers' read *, x
```

It should be

```
 print *, 'Enter two numbers'
 read *, x
```

The error message suggest the same for the last two lines, although in the code you show they look correctly.

After compiling your code:

```
 gfortran sum.f95
```

executable file `a.out` is created. Run it by

```
 ./a.out
```

Comment: What a silly mistake of mine.

Comment: However it doesn't yet work because when I compile it, bash doesn't seem to respond the "read" syntax existing in there and just skip to the next new command line.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Bash does nothing here. Forget bash.

Comment: So, how should I address the shell that I'm using. I use Mac OS X's terminal.
Anyway, although there is a "read" syntax there, terminal doesn't give a chance to input for the variables x and y. Instead it just moves to a new line as if nothing happened.

Comment: The error messages are gone but it doesn't prompt me to input values for x and y either.

Comment: You must show what you do step by step.

Comment: Well basically the same as I pointed out in the original post. I wrote that code (the right one incorporating your correction) using emacs then name and save it as sum.f95.
Next open the Terminal, navigate to the directory that contains sum.f95 using "cd" command. Lastly type in the line "$ gfortran -llapack sum.f95".
Doing this, I expect Terminal would display "Enter two numbers" as my code contains syntax that will print/display this message, where at this time I should enter a number. But it didn't occur. Terminal failed to show this message and consequently I can't input any number.

Comment: No, what you do just compiles the code. It creates an executable file `a.out`. You must run that program by `./a.out`.

Comment: Yes I always got that *.out file after compiling. Ok I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much it works now.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, you are missing a comma.  For the second, it looks that somehow you have missing a line break and the last two lines are merged.

Comment: Where should i put a comma?
I think the last two lines are fine.